# Modifying x and y axis in histogram MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram, axis

So i searched everywhere on the internet for an answer to my problem (especially in stack overflow), but noone seems to give a straight one.

The problem is this: I want to make a histogram for a test that is repeated n times (defined by the user).Each time, the program runs a function to determine the probability of an airplane crashing and it gives out percentages.The x axis must be the numbers from 1 to n, and the y axis must have the probability of crash in % (eg. the 1st-24%, 2nd-67%,...,n-44%).So whenever i try to make a histogram, matlab defines by its own the numbers that must be in x and y axis and also it doesn't put a space between each bar.How can i modify each axis, the spacing and the title of the histogram? I also want each bar to be centered on the numbers.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gca` to get the current axes of the image, and then modify the labels using the `XTickLabel` field.  Alternatively you can use `XTick` to set the labels given a matrix of numbers.  For example

```
ax = gca
ax.XTick = 1:n;
```

Will create `n` labels on the image ranging from `1` to `n`.

The same thing can be done for the y-axis using `YTick` and `YTickLabel`.  The following link provides more details:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html

Comment: Thanks a lot but do i enter these before or after the histogram command?

Comment: You do them after you create the image.  For future reference, this will work with any kind of figure in MATLAB, not just histograms

Comment: I did as you said but what i get is x without any numbers and y from 0 to 1.
Here is my code:

hist(percentages,n)
ax = gca
ax.XTick = 1:n;
ax.YTick = 0:100;

Comment: Does `set(gca, 'XTick', 1:n)` work instead of `ax = gca; ax.XTick = 1:n`?

Comment: No...still same results